# F# rewrite computation expression

Tags: functional-programming, f#, continuations, computation-expression

I'm studying continuations because I want to make some interesting use of coroutines... anyway, I want to better understand one implementation I found.

To do so I want to rewrite the implementation without using the computation expression (continuation Monad), but I'm not quite able to do it.

I have this:

```
type K<'T,'r> = (('T -> 'r) -> 'r)

let returnK x = (fun k -> k x)
let bindK m f = (fun k -> m (fun a -> f a k))
let runK (c:K<_,_>) cont = c cont
let callcK (f: ('T -> K<'b,'r>) -> K<'T,'r>) : K<'T,'r> =
    fun cont -> runK (f (fun a -> (fun _ -> cont a))) cont

type ContinuationBuilder() =
    member __.Return(x) = returnK x
    member __.ReturnFrom(x) =  x
    member __.Bind(m,f) =  bindK m f
    member this.Zero () = this.Return ()

let K = new ContinuationBuilder()

/// The coroutine type from http://fssnip.net/7M
type Coroutine() =
    let tasks = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<K<unit,unit>>()

    member this.Put(task) =

        let withYield = K {
            do! callcK (fun exit ->
                    task (fun () ->
                        callcK (fun c ->
                            tasks.Enqueue(c())
                            exit ())))
            if tasks.Count <> 0 then
                do! tasks.Dequeue() }
        tasks.Enqueue(withYield)

    member this.Run() =
        runK (tasks.Dequeue()) ignore 

// from FSharpx tests
let ``When running a coroutine it should yield elements in turn``() =
  // This test comes from the sample on http://fssnip.net/7M
  let actual = System.Text.StringBuilder()
  let coroutine = Coroutine()
  coroutine.Put(fun yield' -> K {
    actual.Append("A") |> ignore
    do! yield' ()
    actual.Append("B") |> ignore
    do! yield' ()
    actual.Append("C") |> ignore
    do! yield' ()
  })
  coroutine.Put(fun yield' -> K {
    actual.Append("1") |> ignore
    do! yield' ()
    actual.Append("2") |> ignore
    do! yield' ()
  })
  coroutine.Run()
  actual.ToString() = "A1B2C"

``When running a coroutine it should yield elements in turn``()
```

So, I want rewrite the `Put` member of the Coroutine class without using the computation expression `K`.

I have read of course [this](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-bind/) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions) and several other articles about [catamorphisms](https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/catamorphisms-part-six/) but it is not quite easy to rewrite this continuation monand as it is to rewrite the Write Monad for example...

I try several ways, this is one of them:

```
member this.Put(task) =

    let withYield =
        bindK
            (callcK (fun exit ->
                task (fun () ->
                    callcK (fun c ->
                        tasks.Enqueue(c())
                        exit ()))))
            (fun () ->
                if tasks.Count <> 0 
                then tasks.Dequeue()
                else returnK ())
    tasks.Enqueue(withYield)
```

Of course it does not work :(

(By the way: there is some extensive documentation of all rules the compiler apply to rewrite the computation in plain F#?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of `Put` is almost correct. Two issues though:

- The `bindK` function is being used backwards, the parameters need to be swaped.
- `task` should be passed a `Cont<_,_> -> Cont<_,_>`, not a `unit -> Cont<_,_> -> Cont<_,_>`.

Fixing those issues it could look like this:

```
    member this.Put(task) =
        let withYield =
            bindK
                (fun () ->
                    if tasks.Count <> 0 
                    then tasks.Dequeue()
                    else returnK ())
                (callcK (fun exit ->
                    task (
                        callcK (fun c ->
                            tasks.Enqueue(c())
                            exit ()))))
        tasks.Enqueue(withYield)
```

Of course it is not too elegant.
When using `bind` it is better to declare an operator `>>=`:

```
let (>>=) c f = bindK f c
```

that way

- `do!` translates to putting `>>= fun () ->` after
- `let! a =` translates to putting `>>= fun a ->` after

and then your code will look a little bit better:

```
    member this.Put2(task) =
        let withYield =
            callcK( fun exit ->
                    task( callcK (fun c ->  
                        tasks.Enqueue(c())
                        exit())
                    )
                ) >>= fun () -> 
            if tasks.Count <> 0 then
                tasks.Dequeue() 
            else returnK ()
        tasks.Enqueue withYield
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It was backwards as I had inverted the parameters in the bindK function first `m` then `f ` so it had the same signature as the builder. 
Your version of `Put` compiles but then the test does not compile as `yield'` should be `(unit -> K<unit,unit>)`

Comment: I had an error while copying/pasting :). I edited so the parameters can be used in this order `let bindK m f = ...`.
Still, `yield'` shoudl be `(unit -> K<unit, unit>)`

Comment: When I tested I changed `do! yield' ()` to `do! yield'` and that worked.

Comment: you're absolutely right! I wrongly copy/paste again! 
It was late yesterday night here in Paris.